# Scheduling 300 UILocalNotifications for iOS resulting app failure

Tags: ios, max, limit, uilocalnotification

From the ios developer doc, I found that an iOS app could support maximum of 64 local notifications. 
( somewhere in stackoverflow I found it's maximum limit is 128 ).

So, I made an app scheduling 300 UILocalNotifications.

Xcode 5.1 compiled my code scheduling all 300 notifications.
I used NSLog() to verify this.

```
NSLog(@"\nLocal notifications count is::%d",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications].count);
```

And then I began testing. 
I observed notifications over 150.

So, how's this possible?
But I had an issue. When I clicked on my app, it displayed an alert : "NotificationTestingApp" is No Longer Available

Can somebody explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should stick to the advertised maximum of 64.  Other than that, it's not clear what you want explained.

Comment: @trojanfoe , I mean to say that iOS allowed me for more than 64 (even greater than 124) local notifications.  Everything was fine but when I clicked on my application icon, it couldn't be opened. Rather it displayed an alert- "NotificationTestingApp" is NO longer Available.

Comment: Perhaps there is no *hard* limit, and it simply allows you to add as many as you like, however each will have a performance implication and so Apple recommend <= 64.  I doubt anyone knows really, however why do you want 300 notifications?

Comment: @trojanfoe - I just wanted to check if it works or not for my app where I needed notifications to be appeared each alternate week.